# Getting data type as <class Map> instead of int

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I'm relatively new to Python and have been trying to solve some competitive programming problems on HackerRank. In order to receive input, I have to take it from "stdin", and hence I used it successfully in one problem as:

```
...
n,m = map (int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split())
coins=[]

coins=[int(n) for n in stdin.readline().rstrip().split()]
...
```

which would take input of :

4 3

1 2 3

and store 4, 3 in n and m respectively as integer data types and 1,2,3 in a list.

However in a new program I tried the following:

```
from sys import stdin,stdout

n = map (int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split())
arr=[]

for i in range (n):
    x= map(int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split())
    arr.append(x)
```

The aim is to take an integer n from first line, and then read the following n lines containing one integer, and storing these integers in a list called arr. 
This throws a runtime error that says that n is a class map object, not integer.

I tried using type(n) for both cases, and while the first returns int, the second returns map object. How do I fix my code and get my expected input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `map()` returns an *iterable object*. Your first attempt assigned the output to *two variables*:

```
n,m = map (int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split())
```

Python will take an iterable on the right-hand side, and take values from it and assign it to each variable on the left. This means that the `map()` object that was returned is iterated over, and each value it produces is used to assign.

Your second attempt only assigns to *one* variable:

```
n = map (int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split())
```

No iterable unpacking takes place here, so just the `map()` object is assigned.

You have three options to avoid your problem:

- Don't use `map()`, just convert to an integer directly. No need to split either or strip either, there is just the one number after all:

  ```
  n = int(stdin.readline())
  ```

  `int()` doesn't care much about whitespace at the start or end, so there is no need to strip here.
- Iterate manually, using `next()`:

  ```
  n = next(map (int, stdin.readline().split()))
  ```

  Note that I removed the `.rstrip()`; `str.split()` also takes care of ignoring whitespace at the start and end of your string.
- make it an iterable assignment by adding a comma:

  ```
  n, = map (int, stdin.readline().split())
  ```

You could just read all those integers in one line, using some iterable magic:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
from itertools import islice

arr = [int(l) for l in islice(stdin, int(next(stdin)))]
```

`stdin` is a file object, and like all file object, supports iteration. Each time you iterate, you get a line. `islice()` limits iteration to a given number, here provided from the first line we read.

Comment: Thank you for the great and informative answer! I clearly need to do some more reading about maps.